# Returning the reverse of a string using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to return the reverse of a string using recursion but I got a few errors. I'm new to recursion so I don't really know where to start. The errors I'm getting are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 

at java.lang.String.concat(String.java:2027)

at Recursion.reverseString(Recursion.java:30)

at Recursion.reverseString(Recursion.java:30)

at Recursion.reverseString(Recursion.java:30)

at Recursion.reverseString(Recursion.java:30)

at Recursion.reverseString(Recursion.java:30)

at Recursion.main(Recursion.java:46)
```

Here's my code:

```
    public static String reverseString (String inString) {
        String result = "";

        if (inString.length() > 0) { 
            // if the string is empty 
            result = inString.charAt(inString.length()-1) + "";
            result.concat(reverseString(inString.substring(0, inString.length()-1)));           
            return result;
        } else {
            return null;        
        }
    }


    // the testers      

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String inString = "abcde";

        // test the reverseString 
        String revString = reverseString(inString);
        System.out.println(revString);
    }
}
```

Comment: `result.concat(null)` throws the NPE. So, does `reverseString(...)` ever return null? It does, if the string is empty. So you need to return something different. What's the reverse of an empty, non-null String?

Comment: The `return null` in `reverseString()` seems a good candidate for introducing a `null` reference into your recursion.  I don't see how it makes any sense in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception stacktrace is telling you that `null` is being passed to the `concat()` method. The argument to `concat()` is your `reverseString()` method which returns `null` when the string is empty. Instead of returning `null`, you could return an empty String to avoid the `NullPointerException`. Replace the line:

```
return null;
```

with

```
return "";
```

Comment: Thank you! @Asaph

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you, please mark it correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Asaph said you also need to assign this expression
 **result.concat(reverseString(inString.substring(0, inString.length()-1)));**

to your result variable so that it becomes:

```
result = result.concat(reverseString(inString.substring(0, inString.length()-1)));
```

Otherwise it won't work because the concat method of the String class does not return the same object from which it was called